# View Controllers not being displayed in the correct orientation

Tags: iphone, sdk, view, controller, orientation

Suppose I have three view controllers in a navigation controller hierarchy.

This is how I'm handling the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` message for all three view controllers:

```
vc1:
{    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);}

vc2:
{    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
  || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
  || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);}

vc3:
{    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);}
```

So, my initial view controller **vc1** is displayed in portrait mode.  If the device is rotated, nothing happens, which is correct.  I then push **vc2** onto the stack, and it initially display in portrait. I rotate the device, and **vc2** goes into landscape mode, which is correct.  While remaining, in landscape mode for **vc2**, I pop **vc2** off the stack and go back to **vc1**, and **vc1** is displayed in portrait mode - which is also correct.

**So now here is the problem.**

**vc1** Is displayed in portrait, pop to **vc2**, and rotate to see landscape view. Then, pop to **vc3**, and **vc3** slide in landscape mode, even though it only supports portrait.

**I have no idea why this is happening, or how to combat it.  In other words, whenever going back to vc1, it automatically shows in portrait only, but vc3 automatically shows in whatever orientation the previous vc was using.  But you can see I'm using the same code for vc1 and vc3, so it's not making sense to me.**

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: "I'm using the same code for vc1 and vc1". You mean vc1 and vc3, right? You might want to edit that.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I meant "vc1 and vc3", I've edited the question...

Answer (score 0):

How are you actually determining the the device orientation?

UIDeviceOrientation refers to the orientation of the, err, device and should be compared with UIDeviceOrientation... constants.

UIInterfaceOrientation refers to the orientation of the interface. It is determined by reading the orientation of the statusBar, and should be compared with UIInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: I'm using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation.  so, interfaceOrientation is being compared with UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, for example.